# How to configure node on Drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-views, drupal-theming

There is a pattern node is inserted into the slider (in an item):

```
<div class="item"> <!-- Wrap contents -->
    <div class="image"> <!-- Insert image-->
        <img src="<?=file_create_url($content['field_img_slide_1']['#items'][0]['uri'])?>"alt=""/>
    </div>
    <div class="desc">
        <h2><?=$content['field_h1_slide_1']["#items"][0][value];?></h2> <!--Insert title-->
        <div class="info"><?=$content['field_h2_slide_1']["#items"][0][value];?></di><!--Insert title 2-->
        <?=$content['body']["#items"][0][value];?>  <!--Insert text -->
    </div>
</div>
```

The code of the slider:

```
<div class="m-slider">
    <div class="sliderBox">
        <?php print render(module_invoke('views', 'block_view', 'flock_salon-block_1')); // These items are inserted for the slider ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I have only one slide, everything is displayed perfectly. When I add the second slide, it is displayed under the first (incorrectly displayed)

Slider screenshot: http://i65.fastpic.ru/big/2014/0807/96/25ac215abd233ee409ed3dd6459ced96.png

[image]

The second slide lies on top of the first

What prescribe in the template node to fix slider displaying?

Comment: Can really tell from the description that you provided but it could be a CSS issue.

Answer (score 0):

This most often occurs when there are errors in running javascript code or finding a javascript file/library. Open up your developer tools (F12 in most major browsers) and check the console for errors that may be halting your code before it gets to rendering the slider functionality.